# Laravel 5.0 | Changing default actions' names is not working for a resource controller

Tags: laravel, routes, resources

I have created a productController resource in the route.php file like this:-

```
Route::resource('products','ProductController',['names' => ['create' => 'products.add']]);
```

Here is how my productController.php file looks like:-

```
<?php namespace lvtest\Http\Controllers;

use lvtest\Http\Requests;
use lvtest\Product;
use lvtest\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller {


/**
* Class constructor .. requires authentication
*/

public function __construct()
{
$this->middleware('auth');
}
/**
* Display a listing of the resource.
*
* @return Response
*/
public function index()
{
$products = Product::all();
return view('products.productsList', ['products' => $products]);
}

/**
* Show the form for creating a new resource.
*
* @return Response
*/
public function add()
{
return 'Add a product';
}

/**
* Store a newly created resource in storage.
*
* @return Response
*/
public function store()
{
return 'store new product?';
}

/**
* Display the specified resource.
*
* @param  int  $id
* @return Response
*/
public function show($id = null)
{
// $products = Product::all();
// print_r($products);
}

/**
* Show the form for editing the specified resource.
*
* @param  int  $id
* @return Response
*/
public function edit($id)
{
//
}

/**
* Update the specified resource in storage.
*
* @param  int  $id
* @return Response
*/
public function update($id)
{
return 'store new product?';
}

/**
* Remove the specified resource from storage.
*
* @param  int  $id
* @return Response
*/
public function destroy($id)
{
//
}

}
```

and passed the 'names' array to change the default name of the **create** method to **add**.
When I go to localhost:8000/products/add I get a blank page.
How do I fix this

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `['names' => ['create' => 'products.add']` to your resource route will only change the **Route Name**, and not the **Route Method**. This means that you can refer to your route as `route('products.add')` and it will point to the `create()` method on your controller.

When you use `Route::resource` Laravel will expect that you have a `create()` method on your controller. To be able to do what you suggest, you might need to add the method to your controller, and then add a separate route:

```
Route::resource('products','ProductController');
Route::get('products/add', ['as' => 'products.add', 'uses' => 'ProductController@add']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I knew this approach but I was wondering if there is a way to do it using the static method **resource**.
+1

Comment: It also worked for me while using Route::get top of Route::resource?

Comment: but create route is also mentioned in php artisan route:list

Comment: @AbdulRehman yes, the `create` route will always be there if you use `Route::resource`, and yes it will work fine if you use `Route::get` before `Route::resource`, Laravel will evaluate the routes in the same order they appear on the routes.php file

Comment: @gpopoteur thanks for your reply, but something here to understand a problem, like If I replace existing method name from resource controller (create to signup) and use your method to call that signup method which I'm also using by your way, when we have never benefit to replace name, so it's a better we make new method instead of changing if route:resource still show create method. sorry dear if it's sound bad.

Comment: @gpopoteur I'm not fluent, here at beginner working stage in Laravel but I found on internet replacing method but I switch to here. and thanks for your great answer :-)